# Show only the Primary Category (yoast) for custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, yoast

I need to show only the primary category (a function added by default from YOAST) for a custom taxonomy in my template (wordpress).
The taxonomy is taken from the custom "course_category" in learnpress plugin.
It's a taxonomy that adds the categories into the courses created by the plugin.

I would like to create a function to call it in my loops, but i don't know how to write it properly for the custom taxonomies.

I found this code to use for standard categories (NOT FOR CUSTOM TAXONOMIES)

```
<?php
function get_primary_category( $post = 0 ) {
if ( ! $post ) {
$post = get_the_ID();
}
// SHOW YOAST PRIMARY CATEGORY, OR FIRST CATEGORY
$category = get_the_category( $post );
$primary_category = array();
// If post has a category assigned.
if ($category){
$category_display = '';
$category_slug = '';
$category_link = '';
$category_id = '';

if ( class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term') )
{
  // Show the post's 'Primary' category, if this Yoast feature is available, & one is set
  $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( 'category', get_the_id( $post ) );
  $wpseo_primary_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
  $term = get_term( $wpseo_primary_term );
  if (is_wp_error($term)) {
    // Default to first category (not Yoast) if an error is returned
    $category_display = $category[0]->name;
    $category_slug = $category[0]->slug;
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id );
    $category_id = $category[0]->term_id;

  } else {
    // Yoast Primary category
    $category_display = $term->name;
    $category_slug = $term->slug;
    $category_link = get_category_link( $term->term_id );
    $category_id = $term->term_id;
  }
}
else {
  // Default, display the first category in WP's list of assigned categories
  $category_display = $category[0]->name;
  $category_slug = $category[0]->slug;
  $category_link = get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id );
  $category_id = $term->term_id;
}
$primary_category['url'] = $category_link;
$primary_category['slug'] = $category_slug;
$primary_category['title'] = $category_display;
$primary_category['id'] = $category_id;

}
return $primary_category;
}
?>
```

which i can call later with

```
<?php echo '<pre>'.print_r(get_primary_category(get_the_ID()), true).'</pre>'; ?>
```

Comment: What have you done so far to get it to work with your taxonomy instead of category? If you let us know the problems you ran into when you tried, we can help you solve those. You need to do your own research first and at least make an attempt at doing it... we might not all be familiar with this area so the more you do, the more it helps us to help you :)

Comment: i made some attempts on this
For example i used this directly in the loop (without creating a separate function) but i get a weird output (the "if" on error without any category name)
https://gist.github.com/accrane/6334e078e9cc9b140de395f0f197c66d

Comment: So did you use the code in your question or the code you linked to? What *exactly* did you change in whatever code you were using that gave you the error. I'm also not sure what you mean by "*the "if" on error without any category name*"... did you get an error message? Or do you mean it triggered the `if (is_wp_error($term)) ` clause? If so ,how do you know it was specifically that line, and did you print out any debugging info to see what values were causing it to fail there?

Comment: Yes, it triggered the error clause.
I know it was that line because i tryed also to edit the function without any success.
No i didn't debug anything... actually i'm looking other solutions

Comment: The first step for any developer is to debug where the issue is, whether you are going to ask for help or not!! Do some debugging and let us know what is shows, so we can help.